# "This is Highly Irregular"

Tags: riddle, rhyme

This is Highly Irregular.

---

I fly without wings.
I beat without fists.
I jam without crackers.
Who know what dis?

Comment: wait, who jams *with* crackers?

Comment: And where's the rhyme?

Comment: The 3rd part may refers to a DDoS (or similar) attack from a _cracker_, which usually mistaken as a  _hacker_, I suppose?

Comment: @Strawberry - crackers and jam is a somewhat common snack, as [here](http://blog.ideasinfood.com/ideas_in_food/2008/03/saltines-and-ja.html). I always preferred either crackers and cheese or just plain crackers, but who am I to judge..? :-)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Is the answer...

> Sound Waves(Noise)

I fly without wings.

> Sound Waves travel in air and has no wings.

I beat without fists.

> In acoustics, a beat is an interference pattern between two sounds of slightly different frequencies, perceived as a periodic variation in volume whose rate is the difference of the two frequencies.(From Wikipedia).

I jam without crackers.

> I have heard about jamming due to Noisy Sound Waves.

This is Highly Irregular

> The Noisy Waves have Irregular amplitudes.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it a heart?

I fly without wings

> There was a band called The Flying Hearts https://www.discogs.com/artist/1260921-The-Flying-Hearts

It beats without fists.

> Hearts don't have fists

It jams without crackers.

> Based on the heart shape of jam biscuits, in particular jammy dodgers[image: Jammy Dodgers]

Highly irregular

> Arrhythmia is an irregular heartbeat.

Comment: Jammy Dodgers, so underrated

Comment: @Skaterhaz yup, I know my answers wrong, but wrote this up just to get the jammy dodger reference in there. I'm certain that's the sole reason for the upvotes.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe:

> Cloud

"This is Highly Irregular"

> Clouds are in Highly Irregular shapes.

I fly without wings

> Obviously

I beat without fists

> Can be interpreted as many things but i will consider it as: They produce sound in monsoon when they, I don't know, colloid with each other.

I jam without crackers

> They can jam signals.
> Happened many time with me during rain.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> The opening lines to the song "Dub Be Good to Me" by **Beats International**:
>  "Tank **fly** boss walk / **jam** nitty gritty / you're listening to the boys / from the big bad city / this is **jam** hot"
>  Awesome song.

Answer (score 3):

> Time

I fly without wings.

> Time flies

I beat without fists.

> [Beat Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swatch_Internet_Time)

I jam without crackers.

> Maybe related to [Time Jam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Jam:_Valerian_%26_Laureline)

Answer (score 3):

> Musicians

I fly without wings

> Musicians can be pretty fly

I beat without fists

> You keep the BEAT with your FEET

I jam without crackers

> You JAM with your fellow musicians, without prepared music, just making it up as you go. Because you got the BEAT. And you FLY.

:-)

Answer (score 2):

It could be a

> A lightning + thunder bolt

Which can

> fly without wings, beat without fists(as it strikes), jams one's ears when it happens

And for the title

> A lightning and thunder bolts are highly irregular